# Location tracking like in fitness apps

Tags: android, google-play-services

## My goal

Get user location updates for quite long time (e.g. 8 hours) with quite high frequency (e.g. every 30 seconds) even when the application is not running in foreground (meaning the activity where the location tracking was started might be destroyed).

## Issue

I've found many articles regarding location tracking in Android apps.
The newer ones usually explain how to use Google Play Services' location APIs.

The problem is that in most cases, they demonstrate getting location updates in co-operation with `Activity` and `LocationListener`. For example in [Google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). It's obvious this is not what I need. The only approach for long-running background location updates was based on periodical starting (via `AlarmManager`) of a service that run until it got accurate enough location update. However, this approach doesn't seem right for the frequency I need.

So, I ended up with custom idea how to solve the topic, but your critique would be welcomed. Here it is:

## Idea of a possible solution

- `MainActivity` - used just for starting/stopping the tracking by starting/stopping the `MonitoringService`
- `MonitoringService` - a foreground service, where the whole connecting to LocationServices from Google Play services happens. Also, once connected a `requestLocationUpdates` method is called, but its variant with `PendingIntent` object. The pending intent contains intent invoking `MyWakefulBroadcastReceiver` class. **Also, the service holds a partial wake_lock to prevent the device going to sleep and interrupting receiving of the location updates. Here, I'm not sure if holding the wake lock really helps.**
- `MyWakefulBroadcastReceiver` - extends `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, just starts `LocationProcessingIntentService` via the `startWakefulService`
- `LocationProcessingIntentService` - processes the location update passed via intent to it. Network communication performed here. Therefore, it is done in separate service and not directly in the `MonitoringService`

Currently, I have the solution described above implemented without acquiring the partial wake lock in the `MonitoringService`. When connected to debugger in Android Studio, I see the processing of the location updates work. However, I'm not sure what it will do after e.g. 4 hours of running without being connected to laptop (like it is for the debugging purposes)

## Questions

1. Is this approach OK from architecture/performance/battery life point of view?
2. Should I use the wake lock for being sure the device won't go to sleep?
3. If answer to 2. is yes, do I still need to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` for starting the `IntentService` processing the location updates?
4. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is mostly fine. You don't need the `MonitoringService`. The `PendingIntent` will wake your `BroadcastReceiver`, regardless of the state of your app. You don't need a permanent wake-lock. Just use the `PendingIntent` in your setup Activity to `requestLocationUpdates`.

Remember that the location services are already running in the background (as long as the user has enabled location services), so you don't need to run your permanent wake-lock service also (you can wake-lock after `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive()`, but don't forget to release the wake-lock after processing).

The only time you might have to worry about the `PendingIntent` not waking your `BroadcastReceiver` is if the user force-stops your app. In that case, you could choose to respect the user's decision. You can also explore using `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);` which should wake your `BroadcastReceiver` from the stopped state, but I haven't tested this flag in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Few more comments: 1) Location services are running in background, but **does it mean they will prevent the device from going to sleep and thus not sending the location updates?** That's what I wanted to use the wake lock for. 2) The issue with wake lock in `BroadcastReceiver` should be handled by using the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and using the `startWakefulService`.